# Macbook Pro 15, mid 2014 - SSD external adapter/case

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro 15" mid 2014 - A1398 ($1999). It has liquid damage, so it's $1240 to repair = not worth it to repair. I have three questions for you guys..

1. Is it safe to sell it as it is? I'm concerned by my hard drive and all private data I had there.
2. Is there a chance I could take off the hard drive (256GB SSD) and put it into some kind of external case or adapter and use it as external hard drive?
3. If 2 is yes, for what exactly should I look? Can I recommend me such case?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to sell it as it is? 
>   I'm concerned by my hard drive and all private data I had there

Nope. Never sell any computer (or phone)  without a complate wipe.
If the device is broken, remove the storage.

> Is there a chance I could take off the hard drive (256GB SSD) and put it
>   into some kind of external case or adapter and use it as external hard drive?

and

> If 2 is yes, for what exactly should I look?

Googling on "macbook pro 15 mid 2014 ssd upgrade" yields some pictures as well as shops selling this.

Picture what to look for:
[image: Semi random pictures with firm names removed]

In short, look for a mini PCI-e card(ish) with 28 connectors.

You can remove it from the laptop. Not sure how easy that is with your model. Some macs are not made to be trivially opened. But it can be done and it will remove all your data.

> Can I recommend me such case?

Product recommendations are off-topic on Superuser.

But a quick search shows several very expensive upgrade kits like [this](https://azerty.nl/0-6228-723118/transcend-jetdrive-725-solid-state-drive-960-gb-intern-sata-6gb-s.html?gclid=COTzsMexwc8CFUVmGwodvN0DvQ).
Ignore the price, that is including a large shiny brand new SSD. But the fact that they offer an external USB case which fits the old drive means these devices do exist.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I understood this part "In both cases make sure that the motherboard or case is M2 and not classic SATA.". I was thinking about making a "pendrive" out of this ssd drive. So I can plug in into any computer.

Comment: The links I found have a convertor for the Apple format to standard M2.  M2 is a relative new format and is not yet present on all motherboards. And external harddisk cases usually ship with a regular SATA connector, not with M2 or 28pins apple format.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, something like this: https://www.startech.com/HDD/Enclosures/m2-ssd-enclosure~SM2NGFFMBU33 ?

Comment: Something like that for an M2 SSD. Note that you also need the 12+16 pin to M2 convertor. After which it should work but might not fit in the case.

Comment: So, I need a 12+16pin to M2 converter AND external case for M2 SSD. Two things.Correct?

Comment: Correct. That for external use.

Comment: This is kinda weird to me, that there are no "plug and play" cases yet made for apple flash drives. There are so many broken macbooks on the market. What do people do? Sell them with the hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will have is that the adapters are all to M.2 B key and the enclosures you might pair them with are M.2 M key, with the short 5 pin section at the other side, so they won't mate. I've searched for the same solution as you with no luck. Even then, the adaptor is too high to fit the enclosure.

With Apple using their own physical form they are able to charge for data recovery at their retail outlets, or you can buy a dedicated enclosure. This is a bit more expensive than their recovery charge, but you do get a usable external SSD at the end of it. In the UK: [this](https://www.megamac.com/collections/envoy-external-enclosures/products/owc-envoy-pro-ngff-ssd) US: [this](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENPRPCI/)